# Getting JSON IN PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to pass a JSON object to a PHP page, this is my jquery script.

```
        reg_id   = $('#registroid').val();
        razonid = $("#selectRazonId").val();
        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify({myData:{razonid:razonid,reg_id:reg_id}}),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "inc/sitctp0013Procesa-2.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){ 
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

And this is my PHP script

```
 <?php
 $myPostData = json_decode($_POST['myData']);
 $firstname = $myPostData["razonid"];
 $lastname = $myPostData["reg_id"];
 if($myPostData){
        echo "good";
 } else{
    echo "bad";
 }
 ?>
```

but is only printing "bad", I tried doing a var_dump($_POST); but I'm getting a null result.

If I look at the firebug console I can see  that the JSON object it is being sent

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aQ5o.jpg

Comment: jQuery handles encoding the data for you. You don't need to use `JSON.stringify`, drop that part. It should just be `data: { myData: { ... } }`. You also don't need the `contentType` option.

Comment: @meagar if I remove the stringify, the object is sent like this "myData%5Brazonid%5D=3&myData%5Breg_id%5D=70212" and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default return value of `json_decode()` is an object - if you want an associative array, you'll need to pass `true` as the second parameter.

```
$myPostData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: thank you! this is what I was missing, I couldn't find anything related to the file_get_contents while I was researching.

Answer (score 0):

You're double json-encoding your data. You've already told jquery that you're sending/receiving JSON, yet are encoding your object data to json yourself.

Jquery has absolutely **NO** way of telling that the string coming out of JSON.stringify is actually json. It never sees that json.stringify was actually called. It just sees a string, and re-encodes it again, so your

```
{"myData":.....}
```

string comingo out of the stringify call will be turned into

```
"{\"myData\":.....}"
```

All you need is:

```
 data: {myData:.....}
```